# Can you use Steam music using only the Steam overlay?

Tags: steam

Is there any way other than alt+tab to start playing music? To clarify I can only control music that is already playing from the Steam overlay(not in Big Picture mode). This seems like kind of basic functionality.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes** you can,in the very **bottom of the steam overlay** next to the steam logo you should have links for opening web browser,music and settings.

Clicking on Music link opens up the mini-player from where you can select and play songs **from your queue.**

As of **22/08/14** if you are opted in **steam beta** the mini player will have additional **browse** button which will open up your whole library(queue/playlist) and let you browse it inside the steam overlay.

[image]

The bottom links are easy to ignore since they are plain text links,small and near the edge in comparison to other flashy links on the overlay.I have been using steam for years and never did I click on any of those links up until now.

Comment: I know this already. As far as I can tell they are only controls and you have to play music from your library which is only accessible from the desktop unless you are in Big Picture mode.

Comment: Oh I see your issue now,after restarting steam.The problem is that steam doesn't remember your queue through sessions.So if you change games it looks fine(starting music from overlay) but first time you start up steam and open up overlay song list will be empty.But this does look like something they will fix,most people forget to put music to the queue before starting the game.

Comment: Based on @Arremer's comment, I would suggest going to their forum for the beta and making them aware of this bug.

Comment: http://steamcommunity.com/groups/steammusic/discussions#
Here is the link,but people are already complaining about that.

Comment: I get it now. It's stupid that you have to add music to your queue before you open a game. Why not just allow access to your library ingame?

Comment: Updated the answer since valve fixed this issue recently.